# Assets Catalog unassigned category

Tags: ios, image, xcode6, asset-catalog

I am converting all my images for my iOS app from @3x resolution to @2x and @1x. I found that Xcode 6.3 sometimes? puts some of them to the Unassigned set.

At the moment for example I have the @2x icon in the Universal set and the @1x in the Unassigned.

Why wouldn't Xcode recognise and assign the icons to the Universal set? How can I fix that?  I know that I can manually 'fix' that by changing the .json but I obviously cannot do that for all my images.

Thanks!